# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; using multiple query

Tags: mysql

mysql_query("SELECT name,category_id FROM ek_category_description WHERE category_id IS (SELECT parent_id FROM ek_category WHERE category_id =  $productcat_id )");

Comment: its `category_id IN (...` not `category_id IS (...`

Comment: please stop using msql_ functions just use mysqli_ functions for mysql_ is depreciated

Answer (score 0):

**Try following this format when writing an SQL query:**

```
mysql_query("SELECT table.columnname, table.columnname from tablename inner join tablename where table.columnname=tablecolumnname and columnname=$variable");
```

**So in your case it'll be:**

```
mysql_query("select ek_category_description.name, ek_category_description.category_id, ek_category.parent_id from ek_category_description inner join ek_category where ek_category_description.category_id='$productcat_id'");
```